# An Array of objects in php

Tags: php

## I dont understand this why i get this error! is so simple yet very different in php.

```
<?php
    $x=new DisplayTaxonomy ();
    $myarray= array();
    $x->setADTitle("bunkers"); 
    echo $x->getADTitle();

    $myarray =$x;//i also tried array_push($$x, $myarray); same error
    echo $myarray[0]->getADTitle();
?>
```

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DisplayTaxonomy as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\exec-php\includes\runtime.php(42) : eval()'d code on line 9

```
<?php
 class DisplayTaxonomy {
    public $ADTitle;
 public function setADTitle($ADTitle)
    {
        $this->ADTitle = $ADTitle; 
    }
    public function getADTitle()
    {
        return $this->ADTitle;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$myarray = $x;
```

should be

```
$myarray[] = $x
```

Comment: how do i initialize an array to be of a certain type of object For example $myarray[] = new DisplayTaxonomy();//?????

Comment: @jvelez PHP array elements don't have to all be of the same type. `$myarray = array(10, "foo", new DisplayTaxonomy());` is a perfectly legal statement.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `[]` operator to append `$x` onto `$myarray`:

```
$myarray[] = $x;
echo $myarray[0]->getADTitle();
```

Or via [`array_push()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php), which as a function call can be a tiny bit less efficient than using the `[]` lanugage construct.

```
array_push($myarray, $x);
```

The methods for defining and adding to arrays are detailed in [the PHP manual on Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 1):

> As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces
>   array() with [].

[This](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) allows you to both initialize and add objects to an array:

```
<?php  
class DisplayTaxonomy
{     
    public $ADTitle;  

    public function setADTitle($ADTitle) 
    {         
        $this->ADTitle = $ADTitle;
    }

    public function getADTitle()
    {
        return $this->ADTitle;
    } 
}

$x = new DisplayTaxonomy();
$x->setADTitle("bunkers");
//echo $x->getADTitle();

$myarray[] = $x; // Notice no previous array initialization
echo $myarray[0]->getADTitle(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In php, array appending is like this:

```
$myarray[] = $x
```

What you are doing is assigning `$myarray` to your `DisplayTaxonomy` object, and then trying to use your object as an array with array-subscripting (`$myarray[0]`). Thus the error.

As an aside, if you are going to use getters and setters for a property, you should not expose that property as public. Try either `protected $ADTitle;` or just don't use getters and setters.

Comment: i get that it was part of troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you're assigning the object to `$myarray` when you do:
`$myarray = $x`. At this point, `$myarray` is no longer an array, but the object that you assigned to it, namely `$x`.

In your comment in the code, you say that you also tried `array_push($$x, $myarray)`. The reason that this doesn't work is for two reasons.

Reason 1: You are using `$$x` instead of `$x`. If you have two dollar signs (`$$x`), it is the equivalent of `${$x}`, which will first turn `$x` into a string (probably "Object #1" or something like that), and then look for the variable called: `${'Object #1'}`, which obviously doesn't exist. For example, if you have a variable called `$something`, you can also use it like this: `${'something'}`. So if you have a variable that contains the literal string "something", for example `$var_name = 'something';`, then you could do either `${$var_name}` or `$$var_name`. Both cases will get the content of the variable $something.

Reason 2: You're also putting them in the wrong order in `array_push`.

This should work instead:
`array_push($myarray, $x)`

But as others have pointed out, this is the exact equivalent: `$myarray[] = $x`.

I hope that helps explain how things work.